# How can I make an excel file and wirte to it using python?

Tags: python, excel, text, export-to-excel

I need to program a script in python that writes an excel file with three categories and it's input being three text files.

It would be much appreciated if you could help me out because I have literally no idea how to work with excel files.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what I understand your task can be easily achieved using the much simpler python CSV library https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html. You can then import the data in excel, but if you need excel API while generating the file, then I suggest the xlwt library

Answer (score 3):

A reasonable path to follow when processing Excel with Python is Pandas' dataframe. You can get started with reading some [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#excel-files) from them and get experimenting with it.,

```
pip install pandas
```

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("path_to_file.xls", sheet_name="Sheet1")
df.to_excel(filepath, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Starting from here you can do a lot with pandas and excel

I see people recommending xlwt. XLWT keeps formats for excel and does styling which is another reasonable path, but in comparason lacks some functionaility when processing datas. In either cases, both only supports legacy (pre-2007 for Pandas and pre-2003 for XLWT) verisons of Excel